# STDIN is getting listed while listing Azure VMs, hence getting "invalid resource id" error

Tags: azure-devops, grep, azure-virtual-machine

I used the below command to list and stop all the VMs in my account.
VMs are listing, but an additional **STDIN** is getting listed.
This **STDIN** is causing the error **"invalid resource id"**

What can I do to ignore the STDIN??. Your help greatly appreciated.

```
az vm stop --ids $(az vm list --query "[].id" -o tsv) | grep -v "ABDK"
```

thanks

Comment: Try `az vm stop --ids $(az vm list --query "[].id" -o tsv) | grep -v "ABDK" `?

Comment: @NancyXiong My bad, I missed the | while asking question. Actually, we have it. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the VM name by the **STDIN** and want to stop all the VMs that the name does not contain the string `ABDK`, then you can use the CLI command only like this:

```
az vm stop --ids $(az vm list --query "[?contains(@.name, 'ABDK')==\`false\`].id" -o tsv)
```

Update:

If you run the CLI command in the Windows PowerShell, then you need to change the command like this:

```
az vm stop --ids $(az vm list --query "[?!contains(@.name, 'ABDK')].id" -o tsv)
```

Comment: I'm facing this error with this command 

InvalidArgumentValueError: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: "[?contains(@.name, 'ABDK')==\\`false\\`].id"

Comment: @Mangaraju Do you run the CLI command in Windows PowerShell? It yes, then you need to change the command like the update.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Xu Now it is giving the list correctly. By EOD I will try this for stopping the VMs and update you again. thanks again

Comment: @Mangaraju Well, if it works for you please accept it.